# MP4 file not playing in firefox - whats a good video alternative?

Tags: firefox, video, mime-types, mp4

I cannot get my mp4 video to play in Firefox - it simply says " No video with supported format and MIME type found".  Here's my HTML...

```
<video poster="images/video.png" width="100%"  controls autoplay>
<source src="images/polutionbbc.mp4" class="videoplayer" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

The video plays well in other browsers. I have read other similar questions here on Stackoverflow and some people are saying that FF just will not play mp4 video at all due to licensing...

[Playing MP4 files in Firefox using HTML5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488768/playing-mp4-files-in-firefox-using-html5-video)

That assumed therefore, could anybody please suggest either a fix or an alternative video format that plays universally across browsers and how I would convert it?

I am hosting with hostgator and I have checked the list of mime types and mp4 is listed there so I dont think it is that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use .ogg for firefox and opera, according to w3schools you can include both formats to make it work on all modern browsers

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Link: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Here you have some info about compatibility between video/audio formats :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements

Comment: So does that mean having 2 versions of each video file with one encoded in .ogg for Firefox?

Comment: If you want to use video tag from html and have support for all browsers you'll need it afaik :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this - the commenter was correct I need to run both mp4 and ogg videos. To do this step-by-step including converting mp4 to ogg for free using VLC media player see this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNxb6bnTpP0

Answer (score 0):

```
<video controls>
<source src="https://videocdn.whipclip.com/video/55eby.mp4?v=2" type="video/mp4">
<object type="video/mp4" data="https://videocdn.whipclip.com/video/55eby.mp4?v=2" width="568" height="320"/>
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in MP4 with H.264.
</video>
```